# How can I run a command in a shell script function that requires access to the current shell instance?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sh, zsh

I am using a custom package manager called [spack](https://spack.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which allows me to load installed modules using the `spack load` command. It is similar to the familiar `module load` command in many ways. I am using zsh.

I have set up a shell script with a function that I would later like to insert into my .zshrc file. It is currently located in a standalone file for testing purposes, which looks as following:

```
#!/bin/bash
load-standard () {
    echo "loading $1"
    spack load $1
}
load-standard $1
```

When I run this script with source `./script_name package_name`, I get an error message that says

```
`spack load` requires Spack's shell support.
```

To enable Spack's shell support, a file called setup-env.sh must be run which enables the user to make use of the `spack` command.

However, directly typing in the commands `spack load package_name` works with no problem.

I always assumed that running a command from a shell script is the same as typing it into the current shell. How can I make my shell interpret the `spack load` commands exactly as if I had directly typed them in?

EDIT: Placing the function in my `.zshrc` file solved this problem.

Comment: Your shell script runs in a new shell process. Maybe this is a difference. Do you have to run a command to enable "Spack's shell support"? If yes: What does this command do?

Comment: @Bodo I have already tried the solutions suggested by spack. Does that mean that if I place this function into my .zshrc file alongside a function alias and restart my computer I can access this function directly from within my shell?

Comment: @dmmpie : Shell functions are always executed in the same process as the calling shell, unless you explicitly run them as child process. However your question is confusing in that you tag it as zsh, but the script you post is bash. Please make up your mind what shell you want to talk about.

Comment: @dmmpie Please [edit] your question and add *all* requested information to the question. What do you have to do to get "Spack's shell support"? Do you run a command? (What command?) Did you or some installation script put a command in any of your shell's startup files? (What command?) Which shell(s) do you use? What solutions did you try? Without answering my questions I can only guess what might happen if you put the function in `.zshrc` and my answer is "maybe".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with spack, but likely `spack` is a shell function which modifies the current shell environment. That is how `module` works. `type spack` to check.

You can't modify the shell environment from a script, you can from a shell function.

Copy and paste the function `load-standard` to `"$ZDOTDIR/.zshrc"` (for current user, `/etc/zshrc` for all users), source `.zshrc` (`. "$ZDOTDIR/.zshrc"`) and you should be fine (no need to restart).

You can also create a list of functions in a file, and add `. /path/to/functions` to zshrc, to source it.